# firstOrCreate() not inserting and updating

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I want trying updating my table column if table column not exist then i want to create new column and then update this row. But it send me this Error like this bellow:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'option_value' doesn't
>   have a default value (SQL: insert into `admins` (`option_name`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (purchase_delivery, 2018-07-01
>   19:31:31, 2018-07-01 19:31:31))

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    //
    //dd($request->input());

    $admin = Admin::firstOrCreate(['option_name' => 'tag']);
    $admin->option_value=$request->tag;
    $admin->save();
    $admin = Admin::firstOrCreate(['option_name' => 'review']);
    $admin->option_value=$request->review;
    $admin->save();
    $admin = Admin::firstOrCreate(['option_name' => 'purchase_delivery']);
    $admin->option_value=$request->purchase_delivery;
    $admin->save();
    $admin = Admin::firstOrCreate(['option_name' => 'replace_policy']);
    $admin->option_value=$request->replace_policy;
    $admin->save();
    return redirect()->route('admin.settings')
        ->with('success', 'Setting saved successfully');
}
```

Html Code:

```
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select name="tag" style="margin-bottom:15px;" class="form-control">
                                <option value="1" {{$tag !=null ?($tag->first()->option_value==1 ?'selected':''):('')}}>On</option>
                                <option value="0" {{$tag !=null ?($tag->first()->option_value==0 ?'selected':''):('')}}>Off</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label class="control-label">Review System</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select name="review" style="margin-bottom:15px;" class="form-control">
                                <option value="1" {{$review !=null ?($review->first()->option_value==1 ?'selected':''):('')}}>On</option>
                                <option value="0" {{$review !=null ?($review->first()->option_value==0 ?'selected':''):('')}}>Off</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
<textarea name="purchase_delivery" id="summernote_1">{!!$purchase_delivery !=null ? $purchase_delivery->first()->option_value :''!!}</textarea>
<textarea name="replace_policy" id="summernote_2">{!!$replace_policy !=null ? $replace_policy->first()->option_value :''!!}</textarea>
```

Comment: Your `option_value` needs to be passed in the query as well, it needs to be set to have a default value, or it needs to be set to allow for NULL.

Comment: thank i added  `$table->longText('option_value')->nullable();`

Comment: Can you tell me how can i make more dynamic ?

Answer (score 3):

That field, `option_value`, needs a value.

You are only setting a value for `option_name` when doing this:

```
Admin::firstOrCreate(['option_name' => 'replace_policy']);
```

You will need to pass some value for `option_value`:

```
Admin::firstOrCreate(
    ['option_name' => 'replace_policy'],
    ['option_value' => 'some value']
);
```

The first argument is what it will use to build the WHERE query. The second argument are values to use when creating the model (they get merged with the WHERE array). This requires both those fields to be fillable.

**OR**

Make that field `nullable` in the schema, if it is really something that doesn't "have" to have a value when created.